# Any ideas on how to get rid of Cannot find module 'ReactElementType' from 'ReactRef.js' when running Jest Tests

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I upgraded react-native to 0.39.0 and jest to 17. For some reason jest 17 throws a error in multiple tests when I run my test. However Jest works fine?

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'ReactElementType' from 'ReactRef.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:151:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactRef.js:14:344)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactReconciler.js:14:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you're using an old version of [babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes](https://github.com/brigand/babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes) (up to 0.18) with a fairly new React Native (0.38 and up).

See [this](https://github.com/brigand/babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes/issues/62) issue for further details.

Upgrading to version 0.19 of the plugin seems to fix the problem. This works regardless of which version of babel-jest you're using, even up to 18.0.0.

Even if you're not using babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes, you might like to read their [explanations](https://github.com/brigand/babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes/issues/62#issuecomment-269012493) for what might cause such an error, where Flow types are not properly stripped.

(Note that, as you can see on the aforementioned issue, some people start having different errors after the upgrade. That does seem to be the case currently when trying to run the app in iOS, though hopefully that issue will be fixed in the near future.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out react-native 38 and up combined with
"babel-jest": "^17.0.0" causes the issue. 
"babel-jest": "^16.0.0" works fine for me.